# How is the xData is still getting allocated again even though I'm freeing here?

Tags: c, embedded

Here is my code, I'm almost new to coding and working on my first embedded task, seriously gonna need some help. Thanks in advance.

```
1 int *xData;
2 char Pixels[246];
3 uint8_t data[128];
4 char* Pixel_data;

5 while(1)
6 {
7   xData= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
8
9   ReadSamples(data);
10  int j=0;
11  for (int i=0;i<=127;i+=2)
12  {
13  
14      *xData = data[i] + data[i+1];
15      temp_c[j] = (*xData)*(mult);
16      free(xData);
17      j++;
18  }
19  Pixel_data = Create_heatmap(temp_c);  //Create_heatmap returns char* ptr of size 246
20  memcpy(Pixels, Pixel_data,246*sizeof(char) + 1);
21  //Transfers the whole converted data
22  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t*) Pixels, sizeof(Pixels), 100);
23  free(Pixel_data);
24 }
```

1. in `line 7` I'm creating a memory for `xData` using `malloc`, In `line 14` I'm feeding some data to it, In `line 16` I'm freeing it using `free`,  I'm freeing the `xData` in one iteration of `for` loop only but when I see the output as expected. How is `xData` getting filled even after freeing the memory allocated?
2. Can I get better explanation for `line 20`, I have `pixels` with size 246 and I'm copying `246+1` it's working only with 247, if not 247 a byte of data is missing at end. Why is this?
3. At `line 9`, I'll be getting 64 readings from a sensor each in `12bits` and stores as `data[0] = 8 bits` and `data[1] = 4 bits`. This may be `float/int`. I know that what I'm doing is wrong in 'line 14`. How to overcome this?

Comment: Answering your first question, this is undefined behavior.  It might "work" by pure luck, or it might be destroying parts of your program without you noticing.

Comment: What if line 19 returns a NULL pointer, your memcpy will fail, program will crash. Also, your memcpy should copy only bytes equal to destination buffer size.

Comment: What is the point of xData? What does ReadSamples do - does it return anything?

Comment: For third question, why not use `uint16_t`? BTW this will depend on how ReadSamples is defined and works.

Comment: And is this C or C++? Please remove C++ tag is this is not related to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kiner_shah 
My third question has info for `Read_samples` function. If a data is stored in two bytes of memory, how shall I club it together and store or  how to multiply(do some math) the whole 2 bytes of data once as I'm doing in `line 14`

Comment: @Yuvi, to me it's still unclear how exactly data is stored inside ReadSamples. How are 12 bits stored in `uint8_t` array? Please include the code for ReadSamples in the post.

Comment: About the HAL UART you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384201/how-receive-data-with-hal-uart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Accessing the memory address after calling `free()` is undefined behavior, anything might happen. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

   Specifically, there is no such thing as "deleting" physical memory values - most of the time you just mark the address as invalid/not used but the values that were stored there last might still be around. For a great analogy (using the stack, not the heap, but same story either way), check out [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)
2. You are accessing the array out of bounds by copying 247 bytes. This too is an undefined behavior bug. "it's working only with 247" - no it is not, you probably have a different bug elsewhere too.
3. You should probably swap the array to type `uint16_t`.

   Alternatively you could do `(uint32_t)data[i]<<8 | data[i+1];` depending on which byte contains the MSB - this depends on the ADC hardware and endianess. The cast to `uint32_t` is there to prevent shifting on a small integer type - I'm suspecting this is a Cortex M so you bit shifts should ideally be carried out as unsigned 32.

   Note that ADCs often has an option to set how you want data shifted. Assuming Little Endian and 12 bit ADC, then either LSB at byte 0 bit 0 (left-shifted), or LSB at byte 0 bit 4 (right-shifted)

Overall this code is quite naive, which is of course natural if it's your very first embedded project. Some other things of note:

- When dealing with integers in embedded systems, you should only use the types from `stdint.h`. You rarely ever need signed numbers and you should never use plain `int`.
- Dynamic allocation is generally not used in embedded systems because it doesn't make any sense, [see this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581). In your specific case it's just massively inefficient overhead bloat - you should be using a statically allocated buffer instead.
- Similarly, floating point arithmetic should only be used on microcontrollers with an actual FPU. That means at least Cortex M4 .